# Linq 'join ... into' doesn't return joined objects

Tags: c#, linq, join, linq-to-sql

I'm new to SQL and LINQ. I tried a simple code for joining two lists using `join...into` syntax, but the result is not what I expected.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<char,int>> list1 = new []{ 
        new KeyValuePair<char,int>( 'a', 1) ,
        new KeyValuePair<char,int>( 'b', 2) , 
        new KeyValuePair<char,int>( 'c', 3)  };
    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<char, int>> list2 =  new[]{
        new KeyValuePair<char,int>( 'b', 10) ,
        new KeyValuePair<char,int>( 'c', 20) ,
        new KeyValuePair<char,int>( 'd', 30)  };

    var joinQuery = from x in list1
                    join y in list2
                    on x.Key equals y.Key into joinTable
                    from t in joinTable
                    select new { element = t };

    foreach (var el in joinQuery)
        Console.WriteLine(el);
}
```

Output is:

```
{ element = [b, 10] }
{ element = [c, 20] }
```

What I expected is that `joinTable` contains joined records, something like:

```
{element = {[b, 2], [b, 10]}}
{element = {[c, 3], [c, 20]}}
```

Can you explain what the part `... into joinTable` actually did, and why I can use `x` in last select and I cannot use `y`:

```
var joinQuery = from x in list1
                join y in list2
                on x.Key equals y.Key into joinTable
                from t in joinTable
                select new { element = t,
                             first = x,  // OK
                             second = y} // Error: The name y doesn't exist in the current context
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Jon Skeet's blog](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/28/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-41-how-query-expressions-work/) the `join ... into` syntax is translated into a `GroupJoin()`, not a `Join` as you expected.

But what you actually wanted is a real join, so just like that:

```
var joinQuery = from x in list1
                join y in list2
                on x.Key equals y.Key                     
                select new { x, y };
```

---

In your query you were not able to access `y` because the syntax for the `join into` is different. You wouldn't need another `from... joinTable` but had to access `joinTable` directly:

```
var joinQuery = from x in list1
                join y in list2
                on x.Key equals y.Key into joinTable
                select new {joinTable.x, matches = joinTable.y.ToList()};
```

But that would result in `y` having *all matching* elements from `list2`. That's the difference between `Join` (resulting in one "row" per matching element) and `GroupJoin` (with the matches grouped together).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're basically trying to get all info from list 1 and list 2 where they match on a key. If so you can do this:

```
var joinQuery = from x in list1
                join y in list2
                on x.Key equals y.Key
                select new
                {
                    first = x,
                    second = y
                };
```

[image]

You don't need to add this into an arbitrary table, just select from the results of the join.

Comment: I knew that I can do this. I asked two questions, why it is not working with `into` syntax, and why I do not have `y` variable visible if I use it with `into` syntax (in your case `y` is visible under select)

Comment: @Petar - my mistake. I thought you were asking why you couldn't get the result you wanted and was it because of something to do with 'into'